# ViewModel that use BaseViewModel and inherit of Model

Tags: c#, inheritance, design-patterns, architecture

I have n-layer app (Entity Layer - Business layer - Web layer). I like to use ViewModels (in Web layer) to have List of dropdown, etc to erich basic business object (Entity layer) to the UI. For that, I use a BaseViewModel (Web Layer) in every ViewModel that has dropdown or default values, it allows me to just call methods to fill datas, very usefull.

Now I want to find a smart way to avoid to re-type all the Entity Layer properties to VM.

For the moment, here is an example of what I do:

Model :

```
Class CustomObjectModel { 
public int id {get;set;} 
public string name {get;set;} 
public string description {get;set;} 
}
```

VM :

```
public Class CustomObjectViewModel : BaseViewModel { 
public int id {get;set;} 
public string name {get;set;} 
public string description {get;set;} 
public List<possibleNames> string  {get;set;} 
}
```

BaseVM:

```
public Class BaseViewModel{
public List<string> FillNames(){...}
public List<string> DefaultName(){...}
}
```

And I don't want to re-type Model properties to VM... How?

I could use inheritance: CustomObjectModel inherits of BaseViewModel and then CustomObjectViewModel  inherits of CustomObjectModel  but it is really not clean to have reference of WEB from Entites project and it makes me feel uncomfortable with it.

Thanks to help me :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use AutoMapper http://automapper.org/ or something similar like ExpressionMapper http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1009198/Expressmapper-The-New-NET-Mapper

Comment: My issue is that I don't want to re-write id, name, description in the viewmodel in other terms.